# 'parameterValue' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is '**parameterValue**' a default parameter that is passed on an event in Javascript ?
Can anyone explain where this value comes from.

```
<a href="javascript:loadContent('**parameterValue**')">Load Ajax content</a>
```

I found it used in the following article - http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-how-to-use-ajax-in-jsp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of that example, `parameterValue` is not important as it's discarded in the jsp file that is being called. In the javascript the parameters for the call are constructed as:

```
var url="loadJSP.jsp";
url=url+"?q="+str;     /* url looks like loadJSP.jps?q=parameterValue */
```

In the file you'll see that `q` is being assigned as the parameter

```
String q =request.getParameter("q");    /* q = parameterValue */
```

But in the subsequent lines q is never used:

```
String str="This is JSP string loading from JSP page in ajax, loading time :"; 
java.util.Date dt=new java.util.Date();
out.print(str+dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

"parameterValue" is any string value you want to pass through for the page's query string parameter called "q". The following line of code illustrates where it gets concatenated to the URL:

```
var url="loadJSP.jsp";
url=url+"?q="+str;
```

The JSP page on the server will then query the value of the parameter "q" and do something with it. In this instance, though, nothing is done with it. I'm assuming it's only there for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a plain string that you need to pass as a parameter to the `loadContent()` function in Javascript.You can replace 'parameterValue' by the actual value that you want to use.